# Delegates VS IBAction for handling events iOS

Tags: ios, swift, callback, delegates, ibaction

I am new to swift and new to iOS development. I am currently struggling to understand why delegates are used to handle events that happen in the UI.

So far, in the tutorial I am working through, I have only ever done things like the following code segment to handle UI events:

```
@IBAction func fahrenheitFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text, let value = Double(text) {
        fahrenheitValue = Measurement(value: value, unit: .fahrenheit)
    } else {
        fahrenheitValue = nil
    }
}
```

But now the tutorial I am working through is having me use a delegate to to handle another UI event from the same text field. Why is it done this way? What is the point of using delegates rather than just write actions to handle the events?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.range(of: ".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.range(of: ".")

    if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be a new user here. (I looked at your other questions and seems that no one has told you). It's customary to choose an answer as the accepted answer or write comments explaining what you need to know more so you can accept the answer. Whatever you think is the best. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/315277) for how to do that. FYI when you accept an answer you'll gain 2 points :D. And with 50 points you can comment on other answers which is a huge help

Comment: Thank you for that. And also thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`UITextViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate). It'll become easier to understand.

## Responding to Editing Notifications

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(UITextView)
```

Asks the delegate if editing should begin in the specified text view.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(UITextView)
```

Tells the delegate that editing of the specified text view has begun.

```
func textViewShouldEndEditing(UITextView)
```

Asks the delegate if editing should stop in the specified text view.

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(UITextView)
```

Tells the delegate that editing of the specified text view has ended.

---

## Responding to Text Changes

```
func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String)
```

Asks the delegate whether the specified text should be replaced in the text view.

```
func textViewDidChange(UITextView)
```

Tells the delegate that the text or attributes in the specified text view were changed by the user.

---

There is more, but I won't copy/paste anymore you can see yourself. What you see here are things that you can *tune in* if you want.

If you want you can tune in and get the callback of when the user *starts* typing. Or you can tune in and get the callback of when the user *ended* his editing.

**How can you find out when the user stoped or started using `IBAction`?!**

---

Once* you set yourself as a delegate (`textViewInstance.delegate = self`, you can then choose to get any of these callbacks.

*To be 100% accurate, you need to do that, but also adopt the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and then *conform* to it using the mentioned delegate callbacks

Answer (score 3):

Delegate is a design pattern that allows you to easily customize the behavior of several objects in one central object.

Actions are merely user interactions.

It's not possible to replace delegate callbacks with actions. For instance, if you have a `WebView` which fails to load, then how does it inform your object using an action?
In your example, an action cannot return properties like `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and `replacementString`. You need a delegate for that.

Read more...
[Delegate pattern (Apple docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)